# Integral of $(z^2 + x^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

I am studying Griffiths Introduction to Electrodynamics, in which the following integral appears:

$$\int_{-L}^L\left({z^2+x^2}\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\,dx$$

where $z$ denotes a constant, and $z\in \mathbb{R}$

The integration is done without much fuzz about it, as if it was simple.
I tried throwing substitution, and partial integration at it, which didn't bring me far.

I now stumbled upon the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KR22vdvL_3g which deals with a similar integral.
There, use is made of hyperbolic functions and some rather advanced looking identities.
The speaker also mentions that this integral was particularly nasty to solve.

I find it hard to believe that one of the first problems in a rather introductory text should be so difficult, especially because the integration is done in one step, without any explanation.

Are there simpler methods of doing this integral, ones that i am missing?
If not, i guess my question becomes: How to solve this integral?

Comment: Use $x=z\tan t$ or $x=z\sinh t$, depending on whether you want to use circular or hyperbolic functions. The video you linked to deals with a much harder problem, to the point it has [a whole Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed).

Comment: @J.G. interesting, they look so similar. I wouldn't have assumed that having a $-\frac{3}{2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$ as the power would make such a big difference.

Comment: Extra powers of $x$ can do all sorts of things, as anyone who's integrated by parts can attest. A famous example: compare $\int\exp(-x^2)dx$ to $\int x\exp(-x^2)dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $x=z\tan u\implies dx=z\sec^2udu$: $$I=\int_{-\arctan \frac Lz}^{\arctan \frac Lz} \frac{z\sec^2u \ du}{z^3\sec^3 u} =\frac{2}{z^2}\int_0^{\arctan \frac Lz}\cos u du\\ =\frac{2}{z^2} \sin\left(\arctan \frac Lz\right)\\=\frac{2}{z^2} \frac{\frac Lz}{\sqrt{1+\frac{L^2}{z^2}}}\\=\frac{2L}{z^2\sqrt{L^2+z^2}}$$

Comment: This is putting the integration into polar coordinates, isn't it?
I read that the integral of polar coordinates takes a different form:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Polar_Integration
Is it nonetheless valid to just substitute from cartesian into polar coordinates in the way you've done, without having to change the form of the integral?

Comment: @ancient child This is a simple trig substitution, which is of course valid.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $z$ is a (real) constant. Observe that the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2+z^2)^3}}$ is an even function. So
\begin{align*}
I & = \int_{-L}^L \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2+z^2)^3}} \, dx\\
&=  2\int_{0}^L \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2+z^2)^3}} \, dx\\
&= \frac{2}{z^2}\int_{0}^{\arctan\frac{L}{z}} \cos u\, du && (\text{ let } x =z \tan u )
\end{align*}
Now this should be easy to solve.

Comment: The hint at the function being even is helpful (it keeps the calculations simpler)!
Indeed, $z\in \mathbb{R}$ (i update the question to clarify that)